# Joining mongodb collections in meteor and sending data obtained through an API

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am implementing an API using the nimble:restivus package of meteor and I want to join two collections and post the data(documents) obtained through the API.
Joining two collection is working fine using publish and subscribe. But subscribe only work on the client side.
So is there any method to join collection on the server side and use that data in the API??

Comment: you can join the collections inside the the publish function

Comment: But how can I use the documents fetched through publish in an API written on server side??

Comment: if you use restivus check the docs it's great package has all the info in there

Comment: Yes, I use the package but I can't find anything about joining multiple collections or using any other method to include data through multiple collections in the API